# The best and speedy way to write to a file

Tags: ruby

I want to know what the best way is to write to a file, which consumes less memory and less CPU, and is high speed.

I have the below code:

```
file = "some_path/some_name.txt"
File.open(file, 'wb') do |f|
  f.syswrite(params[:file_content])
end
```

I want to know which of `f.write,f.syswrite` and `f.puts` is the best method to write to a file. Also if there is something better than this, then please let me know.

Comment: That's a little like asking what's the best and cheapest car.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I tried all those methods and it din't make any difference in terms of the speed or resource consumption for my test sample data used to write to a file.
Reading Ruby docs din't made it clear to me that which is the best option to use when you need speed or the best option for low resource consumption.